# How to ignore parent directories with wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to scrape a particular online directory of its .flac files. I am typing the following command

```
 wget -r -a flac,FLAC http://website.com/directory
```

Basically this give me all the files I need, but in an annoying way. Instead of just giving me the files in /home/user/music like I would like, it gives me /home/user/music/folder/anotherfolder/somedirectoryidontcareabout/folder500/. This is, I assume because I am scraping from a large directory, but my question is: how do I get wget to put the files directly into my current directory without adding the parent directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the WGET(1) man pages,

> ```
>   -nd
>   --no-directories
>       Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving
>       recursively.  With this option turned on, all files will get saved
>       to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up
>       more than once, the filenames will get extensions .n).
> ```